# split string by arbitrary number of white spaces

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to find the most pythonic way to split a string like

"some       words    in    a   string"

into single words. `string.split(' ')` works ok but it returns a bunch of white space entries in the list. Of course i could iterate the list and remove the white spaces but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just use [`my_str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without `' '`.

---

More, you can also indicate how many splits to perform by specifying the second parameter:

```
>>> ' 1 2 3 4  '.split(None, 2)
['1', '2', '3 4  ']
>>> ' 1 2 3 4  '.split(None, 1)
['1', '2 3 4  ']
```

Answer (score 15):

How about:

```
re.split(r'\s+',string)
```

`\s` is short for any whitespace. So `\s+` is a contiguous whitespace.

Answer (score 9):

Use `string.split()` without an argument or  `re.split(r'\s+', string)` instead:

```
>>> s = 'some words in a string   with  spaces'
>>> s.split()
['some', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'string', 'with', 'spaces']
>>> import re; re.split(r'\s+', s)
['some', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'string', 'with', 'spaces']
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = "some words in a string"
>>> a.split(" ")
['some', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'string']
```

split parameter is not included in the result, so i guess theres something more about your string. otherwise, it should work

if you have more than one whitespace just use split() without parameters

```
>>> a = "some words in a string     "
>>> a.split()
['some', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'string']
>>> a.split(" ")
['some', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'string', '', '', '', '', '']
```

or it will just split a by single whitespaces

Answer (score 2):

The most Pythonic and correct ways is to just not specify any delimiter:

```
"some words in a string".split()

# => ['some', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'string']
```

Also read:
[How can I split by 1 or more occurrences of a delimiter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492415/how-can-i-split-by-1-or-more-occurrences-of-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "".join([w and w+" " for w in text.split(" ")])
```

converts large spaces into single spaces